# Is there any way to write different documentation through swagger annotation for model class which used by different end point resources?

Tags: java, rest, swagger-2.0

I am using Swagger 2.0.6 version and JAX-WS-RS 2.0.1.

I have different 5 endpoint resources (rest API) which uses the same model class. I have attached the screenshot of that model swagger page which is documented.

[image]

[image]

My task is, I need to write different documentation for each endpoint. My issue is, if I make a change in description in the model class, that new description will see in all 5 end point resources.

My model classes are:

PatchOperations.java

```
public class PatchOperations {

    @Valid
    private List<PatchOperation> operationList;

    public PatchOperations() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PatchOperations{" +
            "operationList=" + operationList +
            '}';
    }

    public List<PatchOperation> getOperationList() {
        return operationList;
    }

    public void setOperationList(List<PatchOperation> operationList) {
        this.operationList = operationList;
    }
}
```

PatchOperation.java

```
public class PatchOperation {

    /**
     * {@link PatchOperator} operation to be performed
     */
    @Schema(description = "Operation to be performed", required = true)
    @JsonProperty
    @NotNull
    private PatchOperator op;

    @Schema(description = "Path to target where operation will be performed", required = true)
    @JsonProperty
    @Pattern(regexp = RegExConstants.PATCH_PATH, message = "Invalid path, the path should match regex '" + RegExConstants.PATCH_PATH + "'")
    private String path;

    @Schema(description = "Value used by operation [new value to add, new value used to replace existing value, existing value to be removed]")
    @JsonProperty
    private Object value;

    public PatchOperation() {
    }
}
```

I have tried by creating 2 new class which extends PatchOperations and PatchOperation

```
public class DBRolePatch extends PatchOperations {

    @Override
    @Schema(implementation = DBRolePatchOperation.class)
    public List<PatchOperation> getOperationList() {
        return super.getOperationList();
    }
}


public class DBRolePatchOperation extends PatchOperation {

    @Override
    @Schema(description = "New description for Db role", example = "ADD", required = true)
    public PatchOperator getOp() {
        return super.getOp();
    }

    @Override
    @Schema(description = "New description for DBROLE", example = "/Name", required = true)
    public String getPath(){
        return super.getPath();
    }

    @Override
    @Schema(description = "New Description for DB ROLE", example = "New Project Name", required = true)
    public Object getValue(){
        return super.getValue();
    }

}
```

From the above new changes in design pattern, I am overwriting my new description for all attributes and achieving my task but from above my changes it is making different request body.

```
{
 “operationList”: {
   “op”: “ADD”,
   “path”: “/Name”,
   “value”: “Autopilot”
 }
}
```

The original request body looks like:

```
{
 “operationList”: [
   {
     “op”: “ADD”,
     “path”: “string”,
     “value”: {}
   }
 ]
}
```

Hence, I am getting a 400 Bad request error by saying

> Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of
>   START_OBJECT token

Could you please someone have any idea that how can I achieve my task by redesigning my java classes or with some swagger annotations.

More Information:

This is my end point Resource:

```
@PATCH
    @AuthenticatedSession
    @Path(“/{id}“)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Operation(summary = ” Update DB role.“)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = “201”, description = MessageConstants.CREATED),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = “400", description = MessageConstants.BAD_REQUEST, content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = RestError.class)))})
    public Response updatePartialDBRole(
            @Parameter(description = SwaggerConstants.AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN_DESC, required = true) @HeaderParam(ParamNames.SESSION_TOKEN) String authToken,
            @Parameter(description = SwaggerConstants.DBROLE_ID_DESC, required = true) @PathParam(“id”) String id,
            @Parameter(description = SwaggerConstants.PATCH_OPERATION_DESC, required = true) @Valid DBRolePatch operationList,
            @Context UriInfo uriInfo)throws RestException {
            return delegate.updatePartialDBRoleInResponse(SessionInjectionHelper.getSession(requestContext), id, operationList, uriInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to not add documentation in your model class. Or if you do, add docs there that is common to all endpoints. Then, in each endpoint, you can use some Swagger annotations to write some documentation. Try this:

```
 @ApiOperation( position = 100,
               value = "Retrieve SecurityToken authentication using BODY(String password)",
               notes = "Retrieve SecurityToken authentication using ReturnsId id and password",
               response = ResponseObjectClass.class)
 @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Sucess"),
                         @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "business exception"),
                         @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Server error") })
    public ResponseObjectClass someFunctionality(@ApiParam(value = "request", defaultValue = "an string as example showing your response") @RequestBody YourRequestBodyClass request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws Exception {
    return new ResponseObjectClass();
}
```

@ApiOperation and @ApiResponses are swagger annotations, part of the io.swagger.annotations package in swagger 2.0.

**UPDATE**

Try this: In PatchOperations.java, use generics. Like public class PatchOperations , and the list would be private List operationList; Then the DBRolePatch will change like this: public class DBRolePatch extends PatchOperations{ . . . } and remove the @Schema annotation

Comment: Please have a look in my questions description. I have added my endpoint resource. I am already using all your mentioned annotation for some or other reason, but my task could not be achieved by add description at endpoint. Or Could you please show me how to add for description for all attribute for Single Object.

Comment: Try this:

In PatchOperations.java, use generics. Like public class PatchOperations <T extends PatchOperation >, and the list would be private List<T> operationList;

Then the DBRolePatch will change like this:

public class DBRolePatch extends PatchOperations<DBRolePatchOperation>{
        .
        .
        .

    }

Comment: Try to format my last comment as it contains code. Anyway, it is just a workaround, not sure if it will work. Really you are extending classes just to be able to add different docs to each class. if you have different endpoints, and all of them share the same of similar class, doesn't mean you need to use the same class. Maybe you may think that the data structure is the same, but it may just be a coincidence. I would give a second thought to your hierarchy, you child classes are not adding new functionality.

Comment: Forgot to say, remove the Schema annotation in your child class too.

Comment: {
  "operationList": {
    "op": "ADD",
    "path": "/Name",
    "value": "Autopilot"
  }
}
I did change as per your suggestion. Still it is building wrong request body.

Comment: Can you share the changes you did just in case? I don't understand why the string generated by swagger is still a simple object and not a list

Comment: public class PatchOperations<T extends PatchOperation>  {

    private List<T> operationList;

    public PatchOperations() {
    }
}


public class DBRolePatch extends PatchOperations<DBRolePatchOperation> {

    public DBRolePatch(){
    }

    @Override
    @Schema(implementation = DBRolePatchOperation.class)
    public List<DBRolePatchOperation> getOperationList() {
        return super.getOperationList();
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191278/discussion-between-perimosh-and-neel).